# Strategies for web page transitions

Tags: javascript, html, transition

I've searched the web looking for web page transitions. Traditionally, changes in content have been based on: index.html > nextpage.html. However, I've seen some really nice demo transitions called "web page transitions" but almost all have them have involved visual manipulation of page elements, of the nature: old.element > transition effect > new.element while the page stays the same (i.e., always index.html). To me these are not really page transitions because the demos don't hold real content - just a line or so. While they look nice I don't see how they could work for actual content (say 150 lines of code, aspx objects, new JS scripts, code behind, etc.)

So my questions are:

1. Am I wrong searching for traditional style transitions?
2. Is there something fundamentally correct with those element transitions?
3. Can these element type transitions be made to hold serious content?

The reason for Q3., is that I can't imagine say ten pages of real content being handled by a single default.aspx page. Or am I missing something here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Best wishes - Peter

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/)

Comment: Yes I am! Exactly. You see the transition, but you can also see that the url has changed too. Many thanks Akash.

Comment: The one thing I have noticed about "real" page transitions is that they often flash white, or show unformatted content briefly before apply the transition. The reason for Q1 was whether actual page transitions are fundamentally flawed due to timing/page load problems.

Comment: That is a problem with "real" page tarnsitions. You might've noticed a white background flash on this plugin too. But I think depending on the transition, you can work around these issues. Like if you want fade-out/fade-in transition, you can always make the flash go un-noticed between fade-out and fade-in.

Comment: You could use iframes; the question is if it's worth the extra effort. You need to load the page content twice, synchronize the scrolling of the background instance, and after all this struggling you get something many users will not even notice. (But yeah sure, if optical perfection counts, this is a viable way to do it.)

Comment: Thank you both for your input. It doesn't appear that the solution is inherent to the client server relationship yet, and we'll all have to use workarounds for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've found single page applications (SPA's) which use page transitions. SPA's use a single HTML file and change the content of the page using JS, some frameworks are [React](https://reactjs.org/), [Ember](https://emberjs.com/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/)

If you don't want an SPA you could use CCS transitions on the page load to fade in pages and fade out pages when links are clicked to give a transition effect between pages

Comment: Thanks for your input Henry. Much appreciated. Visual Studio allows me to add five different Angular modules, so perhaps I'll find my solution there. By the way, I mentioned to Akash above about "real" page transitions flashing white, or briefly showing unformatted before the transition. So Q1 was whether actual page transitions are fundamentally flawed due to timing/page load problems. I'm not really a web programmer so apologies for my naivety. All the best - Peter

Comment: You can set the body colour background but the issue with the flashing white before the transition is most likely the way browsers load pages (showing a white screen first) or you're using JS for the transition? If so try CSS, it's better optimised and may get around this issue.
Have you also looked at the [web manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) to set the background colour?
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Henry. I'll look into it. I'm sure it's solvable.

Comment: I realise this is later on and you've probably solved this issue but I wanted to update my answer. Instead of using a prebuilt SPA why not use the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the next page you want. Whilst loading this page you can fade out the current page, push the next url to the history using the [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and then replace the body with the next page you just fetched

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the "flashing" problem on page transitions if you take Akash's approach suggested above is to:

1. Color all the dark elements that "flash" against the white background during page load) as white
2. Make dark images used as lines (e.g., 1px images normally set at 100%) to width 1px

On page load these elements either the same as the background or too small to be noticed. Then after the page is ready reset them to their correct values:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("change01").style.color = "#2E333C";
        document.getElementById("change02").style.color = "#2E333C";
        document.getElementById("change03").style.color = "#2E333C";
        document.getElementById("change04").style.color = "#2E333C";
        document.getElementById("change05").style.color = "#2E333C";
        document.getElementById("change06").style.color = "#2E333C";
        document.getElementById("change07").style.width = "100%";
    });
</script>
```

The elements regain their correct attributes after page load, with no flash. This is so fast that things like fade-in, zoom-in, etc still work nicely.